How do I use a W4 to tell my employer to withold $X from my paycheck?
I received a large refund last year. Something like five times the amount of tax I actually ended up owing. I don't want to give the government a loan each year. I'd like to reduce my withholding such that I pay the government the total tax I actually owed last year plus (let's say) 30%. The ~30% is in case tax law changes and I owe more than last year. I don't want be surprised by a large tax bill. (That being said, if I got such a bill, it wouldn't be catastrophic. I would just pay it.)
As a simple minded person, I want to say to my employer "Please withhold $X each paycheck", but instead they are telling me to fill out a W4. I don't have any idea what the result of the W4 will be. How do I tell them, "just withhold $X"?  Alternatively, how do I fill out the W4 such that "withhold $X" will be the end result?

Did you only work part of the year or have a significant increase in pay that year?

I worked the full year. No pay increase.

It's atypical for a properly completed W4 to result in such a substantial refund, usually that just happens when there is something atypical like part-year work or significant tax credits that weren't accounted for.

You can use the IRS' Tax Withholding Estimator tool to find the appropriate amount to withhold to get as close to $0 owed/refunded each year. That would be the most accurate and I think that's the method I'd steer towards.
Alternatively, if your income and deduction situation isn't too different compared to the previous year, you could reduce your withholding by adding tax credits in line 3 of your W-4 (credits) or line 4(b) (deductions). Just be careful of changing situations (e.g. tax laws, kids aging out of the Child Tax Credit, itemized vs. standard deduction, etc.).
On the W-4, "credits" are applied as a straight reduction in expected tax liability and will directly reduce your withholding dollar-for-dollar (divided by the number of paychecks over the year), while "deductions" will reduce your full-year income calculation and isn't a dollar-for-dollar reduction in withholding.

It is also possible to increase your withholding, to cover taxable income that is not covered by withholding such as (a guess at) expected investment income. To do so, you may need to "lie" on the W4. But the fact is, nobody really cares whether the W-4 information is true or false, the government only cares that you have withheld enough to not be subject to under withholding penalties.

If you are having a ton of extra money refunded when you file your return that means that the W-4 didn't match your true tax situation.
First make sure that the situation last year wasn't an unusual tax year for you. Was there a one time event that may have caused the W-4 to not reflect your true tax situation. That could be things such as getting married, or divorced; a big bonus or a one time payout that had tax withholding that was too high compared to your total income; or a tax credit for buying a EV or getting an energy credit for a new appliance or home improvement.
While doing this initial review find your total tax liability for last year.
Regardless of the tax situation you need look at what has been withheld so far this year to determine what you will have withheld by the end of this year. This is easy if your pay is steady from check to check, it the pay bounces around due to overtime and bonuses that is a more difficult calculation.
Many people like getting a large refund, many do not. The goal for many taxpayers is to make sure that you avoid the underpayment penalty while trying for either a small refund or a small payment due. The easiest way to do this is to make sure that your withholding during this calendar year is at least 110% of last years total tax liability. If your AGI is under $150,000 then the goal only has to be 100% of last years total tax liability.
Since we are already more than 75% of the way though the year, if you have already reached that 100% or 110% goal you can be sure that any tweak to your W-4 this year will not put you to the penalty area.
According to the IRS:Underpayment of estimated tax by individuals penalty

Avoid a penalty
You may avoid the Underpayment of Estimated Tax by Individuals Penalty
if:

Your filed tax return shows you owe less than $1,000 or
You paid at least 90% of the tax shown on the return for the taxable year or 100% > of the tax shown on the return for the prior
year, whichever amount is less. If your adjusted gross income (AGI)
for 2023 was more than $150,000 ($75,000 if your filing status for
2024 is married filing separately), substitute 110% for 100%.

The IRS urges taxpayers to check into their options to avoid these
penalties.

Check your withholding often and adjust it when your situation changes. To do this fill out a new Form W-4 and give it to your
employer. The Tax Withholding Estimator is a helpful tool.
Estimated tax is the method used to pay tax on income that is not subject to withholding (for example, earnings from self-employment,
interest, dividends, rents, alimony, etc.). Use Form 1040-ES to figure
and pay estimated taxes on time.


For help with the w-4 use the irs Tax Withholding Estimator
When the W-4 needs major adjustments the most common things to check is married vs single; number of jobs for the family; did the amount regarding credit and deductions need to change; was there any extra withholding amount listed that now needs to change.
A word of advice, after you complete your tax return in the spring, redo this same analysis to see if the changes made in late 2024 need to be refined in 2025. You don't want to make a change now that will cause an underpayment penalty in the spring of 2026.  You might also want to do this if there is a change income due to a raise. or bonus. You should also factor in things that can change every year: retirement contributions, health insurance premiums, and miscellaneous tax credits.
